# Salvar dados carregados a partir de uma partialView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma `PartialView` com `BeginCollection` onde carrego uma lista de produtos em `Dropdowns` dinâmicos:

[image: Partial View]

Nesse projeto tenho uma relação `ManyToMany` entre Produto e Fornecedor onde tenho a entidade `ProdutosFornecedores`. Gostaria de ao salvar o Fornecedor também salvar os dados nessa entidade que é a relação entre as outras duas.

No meu `Controller` de fornecedores tenho o seguinte método:

```
 public ActionResult getProducts()
 {
      ViewBag.Products = db.Products.ToList();
      return PartialView("_Product", new ProductsSuppliers());
 }
```

A Partial está dessa maneira:

```
@model CodingCraft01.Models.ProductsSuppliers
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("ProductsSuppliers"))
{
    <div id="productRow" class="productRow">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Product, new SelectList(ViewBag.Products, "IdProduct", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" id="deleteRow" class="deleteRow" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">Delete</a>
    </div>
}
```

E na View de Fornecedores:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Supplier</h4>
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAddProduct" href="javascript:void(0);">Add Product</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <div class="form-group" id="new-product"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

O que preciso fazer pra salvar os dados do `Fornecedor` e da entidade `ProdutosFornecedores` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente você já está usando o `BeginCollectionItem`, então irei responder da premissa que toda a implementação dele está correta.

Pelo seu código, você está passando a propriedade de navegação no `DropDownList`, e não o id do produto. Altere essa parte para isso:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.IdProduct, new SelectList(ViewBag.Products, "IdProduct", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Feito isso você irá passar o `IdProduct` para controller. Após isso, salve normalmente.

Vale ressaltar que se estiver utilizando o `Scaffolding` do Visual Studio, ele não adiciona a lista automaticamente, por padrão, no `Model Biding`. Adicione a lista no `Bind` para funcionar, tipo assim:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "IDSupplier,Name,Products")] Supplier supplier)
```